# Bind Keyboard to TextInput while it is hidden on Android Kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have created a simple kivy app which is successfully running on windows. It takes barcode of products as input and proceed further. I have designed my own keypad for my application + It takes input from Barcode Scanner as well (Scanned barcode is being placed in focused TextInput). For this, I have set

```
    Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')
```

which works perfectly fine.

Now, I want to run this app on android. On android, when a TextInput get's focus the android's keyboard becomes visible, which I don't want. I set TextInput property **'keyboard_mode'** to **'managed'** for this but it stops putting scanned barcode (from Barcode Scanner) in TextInput (as system keyboard will not be requested now).

What I want, hide the keyboard but it remain binded with focused TextInput, to access input from Barcode Scanner. I am stuck here, any help will be highly appreciated.

I am using: kivy==2.0.0, python==3.7.9 and buildozer to package application for android.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas but I first want to double check that you've put the `Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')` statement in the right place.

This needs to come before *everything*, i.e. the first two lines of your your main.py file should look like this:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

# etc.
```

The reason I ask this, is because writing `Config.set()` after importing `App` has no effect. On your computer I believe the default `keyboard_mode` is `''` which is to simply choose the best option, which coincidentally is `system`. This can give the illusion of a working `Config.set()`.

Comment: Hi jda5,
Yes, the configs are being set at top of main file. But It works okay on Windows, I am facing issues on android.

Answer (score 0):

Add your related code piece textinput/textfield focus=True.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kivyy=Builder.load_string("""

<MyContent>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:box_layout
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'Focus textinput and focus where except textinput'
        TextInput:
            id:txt
            text:''
            hint_text:'type here'
            on_focus:root.check_focus()
 """)

class MyContent(BoxLayout):

    def check_focus(self):
        if self.ids.txt.focus==True:
            print('here your keyboard design when focus')
            self.my_keyboard=GridLayout(rows=2, cols=2, size=self.size)
            for i in range(4):
                self.but=Button(text=str(i), color='white')
                self.but.bind(on_release=lambda _,text=self.but.text: self.write(text))          
                self.my_keyboard.add_widget(self.but)
                
            self.ids.box_layout.add_widget(self.my_keyboard)
        else:
            print('delete your keyboard when unfocus')
            self.ids.box_layout.remove_widget(self.my_keyboard)
            
    def write(self, text):
        self.ids.txt.focus=True
        self.ids.txt.text += text

class exampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
           
        return MyContent()

kv=exampleApp().run()
```

Look 'on_release' and focus=True when press on button.